# Setting sorting | order on filter_log_events method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to figure it out if it's possible to set different order on cloudwatch-logs#filter_log_events

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/CloudWatchLogs/Client.html#filter_log_events-instance_method

above is Ruby sdk example. My issue is that it returns from oldest to newest, where I need to filter and return from newest to oldest. This is really a nuisance.

I'd appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way do have the sorting possible is within your application.

You can pull the log events by batch using `limit` or along with `start_time` and `end_time` filter to get the desired blocks of log events.

And from there you can sort it within the application.